# File can be opened only by root user..Wrong permissions given, i guess

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, file-handling

My program basically runs a executable file with command line arguments.
A child process is forked and the output of the child process is taken in the file "filename".

**The problem is** that the file is made and the data is written but it can only be opened by the root user.. **How can make it readable to the user who invoked the program?**

The code is:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>      //strcpy() used
    #include<malloc.h>      //malloc() used
    #include<unistd.h>      //fork() used
    #include<stdlib.h>      //exit() function used
    #include<sys/wait.h>    //waitpid() used
    #include<fcntl.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
char *command;
char input[256];
char **args=NULL;
char *arg;
int count=0;
char *binary;
pid_t pid;
int fdw;

printf("Enter the name of the executable(with full path)");
fgets(input,256,stdin);

command = malloc(strlen(input));
strncpy(command,input,strlen(input)-1);

binary=strtok(command," ");
args=malloc(sizeof(char*));

args[0]=malloc(strlen(binary)+1);
strcpy(args[0],binary);

while ((arg=strtok(NULL," "))!=NULL)
{
    if ( count%10 == 0) args=realloc(args,sizeof(char*)*10);
    count++;
    args[count]=malloc(strlen(arg));
    strcpy(args[count],arg);
}
args[++count]=NULL;

if ((fdw=open("filename",O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_CREAT|0700)) == -1)
    perror("Error making file");
close(1);
dup(fdw);

if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
{
    perror("Error forking...\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (pid == 0)   execvp(args[0],&args[0]);
else
{
    int status;
    waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does ls -l say when pointed at the file?

Comment: ------xr-- 1 shadyabhi shadyabhi  7342 2010-02-03 01:39 filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-read the manpage for open, you are not passing the file mode argument correctly and causing the flags to be messed up in the process.

Comment: just changed the open() call to:- open("filename",O_WRONLY|O_EXCL|O_CREAT,777)

& the problem got solved....

Comment: Don't use 777; that's a decimal number, not octal.  Don't use 0777; the file is not intended to be executable, and should probably not be world-writable either.  Use 0644 or even 0444 (or perhaps 0664 if you trust the rest of the people who belong to your group).

Comment: @Shadyabhi: Or use symbolic names if you don't like octal constants, e.g. `S_IRUSER|S_IWUSER|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH`.

Comment: The best value for mode for a non-executable file is `0666` or `S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH`. The provided mode is combined with the user's umask to get the final permission bits. On systems where each user has a private group, the default umask is usually `0002` when there is a single users group it is usually `0022`. The final permissions are then `0664` and `0644` respectively. In general, specify the same bits for user group and other so the user has control over the final permissions. See the umask(2) manpage (http://linux.die.net/man/2/umask) for more details.

Comment: Ok. i got u. I should not use it... thanx for pointing it out.